# mongodb aggregate multiple arrays

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using MongoDB version v3.4. I have a `documents` collection and sample datas are like this:

```
{
    "mlVoters" : [ 
        {"email" : "a@b.com", "isApproved" : false}
    ],
    "egVoters" : [ 
        {"email" : "a@b.com", "isApproved" : false}, 
        {"email" : "c@d.com", "isApproved" : true}
    ]
},{
    "mlVoters" : [ 
        {"email" : "a@b.com", "isApproved" : false}, 
        {"email" : "e@f.com", "isApproved" : true}
    ],
    "egVoters" : [ 
        {"email" : "e@f.com", "isApproved" : true}
    ]
}
```

Now if i want the count of distinct email addresses for mlVoters:

```
db.documents.aggregate([
  {$project: { mlVoters: 1 } },
  {$unwind: "$mlVoters" },
  {$group: { _id: "$mlVoters.email", mlCount: { $sum: 1 } }},
  {$project: { _id: 0, email: "$_id", mlCount: 1 } },
  {$sort: { mlCount: -1 } }
])
```

Result of the query is:

```
{"mlCount" : 2.0,"email" : "a@b.com"}
{"mlCount" : 1.0,"email" : "e@f.com"}
```

And if i want the count of distinct email addresses for egVoters i do the same for egVoters field. And the result of that query would be:

```
{"egCount" : 1.0,"email" : "a@b.com"}
{"egCount" : 1.0,"email" : "c@d.com"}
{"egCount" : 1.0,"email" : "e@f.com"}
```

So, I want to combine these two aggregation and get the result as following (sorted by totalCount):

```
{"email" : "a@b.com", "mlCount" : 2, "egCount" : 1, "totalCount":3}
{"email" : "e@f.com", "mlCount" : 1, "egCount" : 1, "totalCount":2}
{"email" : "c@d.com", "mlCount" : 0, "egCount" : 1, "totalCount":1}
```

How can I do this? How should the query be like? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you add a field `voteType` in each vote. This field indicates its type. Having this field, you don't need to keep the votes in two separate arrays `mlVoters` and `egVoters`; you can instead concatenate those arrays into a single array per document, and unwind afterwards.

At this point you have one document per vote, with a field that indicates which type it is. Now you simply need to group by email and, in the group stage, perform two conditional sums to count how many votes of each type there are for every email.

Finally you add a field `totalCount` as the sum of the other two counts.

```
db.documents.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      mlVoters: {
        $ifNull: [ "$mlVoters", []]
      },
      egVoters: {
        $ifNull: [ "$egVoters", []]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "mlVoters.voteType": "ml",
      "egVoters.voteType": "eg"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      voters: { $concatArrays: ["$mlVoters", "$egVoters"] }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$voters"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      email: "$voters.email",
      voteType: "$voters.voteType"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$email",
      mlCount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            "if": { $eq: ["$voteType", "ml"] },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      },
      egCount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            "if": { $eq: ["$voteType", "eg"] },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      totalCount: {
        $sum: ["$mlCount", "$egCount"]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Your answer looks quite reasonable but it is giving me `"errmsg" : "$concatArrays only supports arrays, not object"`. Is that because instead of being simple array they are array of objects?

Comment: Do you have any document in the collection which does not have both a `egVoters` and `mlVoters` arrays, even if empty? That would explain this error, because in that case  `$addFields: { "mlVoters.voteType": "ml" }` would create a field like `"mlVoters" : { "voteType" : "ml" }`. You can solve that by creating the (empty) arrays first if they don't exist.

Comment: Yes i have. How can i create empty arrays if they don't exist?