# Aggregate multiple arrays by field value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

With a document as shown below, I am trying to aggregate the data so my final output is the sum of each users `received` and `sent` values.

**Document**

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "received" : [
        { "name" : "david", "value" : 15 }, 
        { "name" : "sarah", "value" : 10 }, 
        { "name" : "sarah", "value" : 15 }
    ],
    "sent" : [ 
        { "name" : "david", "value" : 10 }, 
        { "name" : "sarah", "value" : 20 }, 
        { "name" : "david", "value" : 15 }
    ]
}
```

**Desired Result (or similar)**

```
{
    "name": "david",
    "received": 15,
    "sent": 25
},
{
    "name": "sarah",
    "received": 25,
    "sent": 20
}
```

I have tried to unwind received and sent, but I am ending up with a lot of duplicates and honestly I have no idea if this sort of output can even be created without bringing the dataset into my client first.

Further searching of StackOverflow has lead me to [mongodb aggregate multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52978790/mongodb-aggregate-multiple-arrays) that provides a suitable answer. I have flagged this as a duplicate.

**My final solution, created by following the above post, is as follows;**

```
[
  {
    '$addFields': {
      'received.type': 'received', 
      'sent.type': 'sent'
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'movements': {
        '$concatArrays': [
          '$received', '$sent'
        ]
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$movements'
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'name': '$movements.name', 
      'type': '$movements.type', 
      'value': '$movements.value'
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$name', 
      'sent': {
        '$sum': {
          '$cond': {
            'if': {
              '$eq': [
                '$type', 'sent'
              ]
            }, 
            'then': '$value', 
            'else': 0
          }
        }
      }, 
      'received': {
        '$sum': {
          '$cond': {
            'if': {
              '$eq': [
                '$type', 'received'
              ]
            }, 
            'then': '$value', 
            'else': 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `$match` stage on the top to filter the documents

- `$facet` to compute two different result by sent and received on same document
- `$group` to merge the by sent and received fields of previous stage
- `$unwind` & `$unwind` to unwind the merged array of array
- `$replaceRoot` to replace root with byBoth
- `$group` to merge the results back
- `$project` to filter and project required fields only

aggregation pipeline

```
db.ttt.aggregate([
    {$facet : {
        "byReceived" :[
            {$unwind : "$received"},
            {$group: {_id : "$received.name", received : {$sum : "$received.value"}}}
        ],
        "bySent" :[ 
            {$unwind : "$sent"},
            {$group: {_id : "$sent.name", sent : {$sum : "$sent.value"}}}
        ]
    }},
    {$group: {_id:null, byBoth : {$push :{$concatArrays : ["$bySent", "$byReceived"]}}}},
    {$unwind : "$byBoth"},
    {$unwind : "$byBoth"},
    {$replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$byBoth" }},
    {$group : {_id : "$_id", sent : {$sum : "$sent"}, received : {$sum : "$received"}}},
    {$project : {_id:0, name:"$_id", sent:"$sent", received:"$received"}}
])
```

result

```
{ "name" : "david", "sent" : 25, "received" : 15 }
{ "name" : "sarah", "sent" : 20, "received" : 25 }
```

Comment: Very neat and tidy. I like this response. The processing times between your submission and the duplicate one I found are roughly identical.